# PETSc example not working

Tags: c, makefile, cygwin, petsc

I have Windows 7 OS. 
I have followed the instructions from the [PETSc web page](http://www.mcs.anl.gov/petsc/documentation/installation.html#windows); in the command prompt of VS 2005 I have opened cygwin and installed PETSc with the command:

```
./configure --with-cc='win32fe cl' --with-fc=0 --with-mpi=0 --download-f2cblaslapack
```

I tried to run the following example from the web page:

```
cd src/ksp/ksp/examples/tutorials

make ex2
```

the ex2.c is a c program code. I get the following error:

```
$ make ex2

makefile:18: /conf/variables: No such file or directory

makefile:19: /conf/rules: No such file or directory

makefile:1151: /conf/test: No such file or directory

make: *** No rule to make target `/conf/test'.  Stop.
```

What is causing this?

(and more importantly) 
How do I fix it?

*edit: I could use a general answer as well, because at the moment I don't really even know what to Google for and I don't feel like just contacting PETSc support for everything.

---

I've decided to work on Ubuntu. So now, here s the deal. After installation I write:

> gcc -I$PETSC_DIR/include -L$PETSC_DIR/$PETSC_ARCH/lib -libpetsc ex2

in command line. I get the erros massage:

> /usr/bin/ld: cannot find -libpetsc
>   ex2: In function `_start':
>   (.text+0x1bc4): multiple definition of`_start'
>   /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.6/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/crt1.o:(.text+0x0): first defined here
>   ex2: In function `_fini':
>   (.fini+0x0): multiple definition of`_fini'
>   /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.6/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/crti.o:(.fini+0x0): first defined here
>   ex2:(.rodata+0x0): multiple definition of `_IO_stdin_used'
>   /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.6/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/crt1.o:(.rodata.cst4+0x0): first defined here
>   ex2: In function`__data_start':
>   (.data+0x0): multiple definition of `__data_start'
>   /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.6/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/crt1.o:(.data+0x0): first defined here
>   ex2: In function`__data_start':
>   (.data+0x8): multiple definition of `__dso_handle'
>   /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.6/crtbegin.o:(.data+0x0): first defined here
>   ex2: In function`_init':
>   (.init+0x0): multiple definition of `_init'
>   /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.6/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/crti.o:(.init+0x0): first defined here
>   collect2: ld returned 1 exit status

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned on the [PETSc web page](http://www.mcs.anl.gov/petsc/documentation/installation.html) under section *Encounter problems?* for problem related to `make` you need to set `PETSC_DIR` and `PETSC_ARCH` printed by configure.

*What is causing this?*:
The `makefile` in `src/ksp/ksp/examples/tutorials` directory refers to `PETSC_DIR` to include the configuration files i.e.

```
include ${PETSC_DIR}/conf/variables
include ${PETSC_DIR}/conf/rules

...
include ${PETSC_DIR}/conf/test
```

Now as you are executing `make` as just `make ex2` (as from the error it indicates that you have not set `PETSC_DIR` variable), `${PETSC_DIR}` is empty thus `make` tries to include `/conf/variables`, `/conf/rules` & `/conf/test` files which are not present.

*How do I fix it?*
You have to run `make` as mentioned on the website as
`make PETSC_DIR=<dir_output_from_configure> PETSC_ARCH=<arch_output_from_configure> ex2`
Before that you need to build the source correctly. To clarify from what you have mentioned in the question `./configure ...` does not install PETSc but only configures the source for building. You need to run `make`. When you run `configure` if it was successful, it will output the configuration details including `PETSC_DIR` and `PETSC_ARCH`. Sample output:

```
./configure --with-mpi=0
===============================================================================
             Configuring PETSc to compile on your system                       
===============================================================================
TESTING: alternateConfigureLibrary from PETSc.packages.petsc4py(config/PETSc/packages/petsc4py.py:65)                                                                   Compilers:
...
...
PETSc:
  PETSC_ARCH: arch-linux2-c-debug
  PETSC_DIR: /XXXX/petsc-3.3-p1
  Clanguage: C
  Scalar type: real
  Precision: double
  shared libraries: disabled
  dynamic loading: disabled
  Memory alignment: 16
xxx=========================================================================xxx
 Configure stage complete. Now build PETSc libraries with (cmake build):
   make PETSC_DIR=/XXXX/petsc-3.3-p1 PETSC_ARCH=arch-linux2-c-debug all
 or (experimental with python):
   PETSC_DIR=/XXXX/petsc-3.3-p1 PETSC_ARCH=arch-linux2-c-debug ./config/builder.py
xxx=========================================================================xxx
```

Then you have run `make PETSC_DIR=/XXXX/petsc-3.3-p1 PETSC_ARCH=arch-linux2-c-debug all` as mentioned in the output of `configure`. This will build the libraries. Now you should be able to build the example. (Please note that this was run on Linux, you should pretty much be able to do the same on cygwin)
Side note: There does not seem to be any need to set `PETSC_ARCH` for building the example, you should be able to build with `make PETSC_DIR=<dir_output_from_configure> ex2`

Hope this helps!

Comment: Well. I forgot to mention. After running the "./configure..." code as mentioned above I did what the prompt asked of me i.e. "make PETSC_DIR....." etc. I came as far as to have read that the library compiling was successful. Afterwards the "make ex2" reported the error mentioned in my question. now, when I try to run "make PETSC_DIR..... ex2" with the added command of "PETSC_DIR....." as you mentioned it does something for me at least (prints out some lines about some folders). I don't really know if what I get is right but it's definitely not an error massage.

Comment: @user1487833: So are you able to build and execute the examples? If not, you can post the console messages. Maybe something can be figured out

Comment: I have built the examplee, yes. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem. You just need one fix. In the makefile that shows the above mentioned error, just give the value for the `PETSC_DIR` variable in the makefile. For example, for me it was

> PETSC_DIR=/Users/kanikas/Documents/research/petsc/petsc-3.5.2

Note: `PETSC_DIR` should be the root directory for petsc.

Comment: You can put variables within backticks to add syntax highlighting to them, and similarly indent by four spaces for code blocks: http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting.

Answer (score 1):

I am working adding the export path directly in ~/.bashrc. That way I do not need to write the path over and over again.

```
sudo nano ~/.bashrc
```

Go to the last line of the file:

```
#PETScXXX
export PETSC_DIR=/home/username/PETSc/petsc-3-8
export PETSC_ARCH=arch-linux2-c-debug
```

Everytime that you start the shell you will be able to access the correct petsc path and libraries.

I hope this can be helpful to someone.
(Running Xubuntu 16.04 64bits)